# Core Data select the first and the last records in one fetchRequest

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

I have a list of items in an entity in Core Data on the iphone all of them have an item_id integer attribute. I need to return the highest numbered item_id and the lowest numbered item_id that are in the table with **one** fetch request. I do not have any knowledge of what those numbers might be as they do not start at 0 and go up.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Again, I know I can do it with 2 separate fetch requests, is there a way to do it with just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a tricky one to do in only ONE fetch. I would do two fetches using the MAX and MIN functions / expressions. e.g.

```
NSExpression *minExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@”min:”
arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
```

If you absolutely have to do it in ONE fetch then I can only think to do a fetchAll and sort by the id, then get the first and last via:

```
[objects objectAtIndex:0]
[objects lastObject]
```

Update 1:
Looks like this guy has a solution:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/1/19/core-data-queries-using-expressions.html

Comment: The key to his solution is the multiple expressions:
`[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:earliestExpressionDescription,
latestExpressionDescription, nil]];`
Very useful, I didn't know you could do that myself.